# Docker Node Sass does not yet support your current environment

Tags: node.js, docker, sass

```
FROM node:latest as nodeBuilder
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY ./webapp /var/www/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
RUN rm -rf node_module
```

when i run this got this error

> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use

```
FROM node:12.22.1 as nodeBuilder

WORKDIR /var/www/app


COPY ./backend /var/www/app
RUN  rm -rf node_module
RUN npm install
 RUN npm rebuild node-sass
RUN npm run build
RUN rm -rf node_module
```

and it's work because of node v15 dose not support node_sass